# update a value with addition or subtration

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am trying to add or even remove a value and update the table with the new value.
Say I have an agent who has 5 points. I do not want to add a new line or over write the existing with a new value of saying another 5 points. I want it to be 5+5 points of 5 - 5 points. then Update the value in the column.

So far I have found

```
("Insert Into Bee_Sheet(Agents_Name, Points, Date_added)Values(" + AN + "','" + PNumber + "','" + DateTime.Now + "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Points=VALUES(Points)-VALUES(PNumber)
```

but I error out on my AN which is the agent's name we have in AD. Tells me there is a syntax error near their name which we use first.last name scheme. This should not affect the out come.

So my question is what would be the best way to rewrite the SQL command to be able to add or remove a certain amount from a value and then update it?

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: My first recommendation is to use parameters instead of concatenating values together to create your SQL command. I believe the issue is that you don't have a single quotes before `AN`, but with parameters you don't have to worry about when you do or do not need quotes.

Comment: You aren't more worried about the syntax error?  Seems like that's more important than your math problem.  The answer to that problem is DON'T CONCATENATE SQL.  Use parameters or whatever MySQL calls them.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  You say "I do not want to add a new line or over write the existing with a new value" but thats exactly what your sample SQL does

Comment: Right now when I try to add a user with a value for the month it is adding a whole new line with name points and date instead of updating the existing one. The points I all i want to have updated with a new value based on what was there and what is being added or removed.

Comment: Then you need `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

For your syntax error: Your query was missing an opening single quote before your "AN" value.

For your actual question about updating the value, it looks like you're on the right track. Assuming, of course, that you do have a `unique index` or `primary key` on your Bee_Sheet table. If you don't have an unique index or pkey, then your query will only ever do the insert.

My only suggestion would be that your UPDATE should probably add PNumber to Points, rather than subtract it.

```
Insert Into Bee_Sheet
    (Agents_Name, Points, Date_added)
Values
    ('" + AN + "','" + PNumber + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE
        Points=VALUES(Points)+VALUES(PNumber)
```